# creating variable from a matrix R

Tags: r, variables, matrix

i'm tryng to create a set of variables from a matrix, this is my code

```
matrix<-cbind(paste("a",letters[1:11],sep=""), 
paste("b",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("c",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("d",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("e",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("f",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("g",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("h",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("i",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("j",letters[1:11],sep=""),
paste("k",letters[1:11],sep=""))
```

so i've got a matrix with all the combination between the letters, aa, ab, ac and so on;
what can I do if i want create variables with the same name and assign a value of each?
for example

```
aa<-0
ab<-0
```

and so on; is there a method to do automatically?thanks

Comment: To create a matrix with combinations, one does *not* write them by hand. You don't need R for that, just grab a paper and a pencil. One possible way to do this programatically, is `outer(letters[1:11], letters[1:11], paste0)`

Comment: This is a really terrible idea as pointed many times on SO. You should not be creating separate variables since it will be a real PITA to later reference them separately.

Comment: This is a terrible idea since you will try to create a variable by the name "if" which is a reserved word.. I would rethink this if I were you.

Comment: @Dr.Mike reserved words is the least of his problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this alternate strategy:

```
> m <- matrix(NA, 10, 10, dimnames=list(letters[1:10], letters[1:10]) )
> m[]  <- outer(1:10, 1:10, FUN="-")
> m
  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
a 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9
b 1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8
c 2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
d 3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
e 4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
f 5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
g 6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3
h 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2
i 8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1
j 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

Now you can access a single element with a letter pair:

> m['d','f']
>   [1] -2